# How do I make my bot send a message everytime im gonna be doing an update so that my clients know? (discord.js)

Tags: discord, discord.js

I need to know how to make it so whenever im doing updates to  my bot it sends like a message to each server in a channel called announcements and then it lets everyone know that it is being updated and that there will be down time? if anybody knows help please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by checking every server your bot is in for a channel named "announcements", then sending a message to that channel.

This assumes that your bot was initialized under the variable named `client`.

```js
// Set our message. This can also be an Attachment or RichEmbed
var message = "Going offline due to updates! Be back in 10 minutes.";

// For all the servers this bot is in,
client.guilds.forEach((guild) => {
    // Look for a channel named "announcements".
    var channel = guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "announcements");
    // Make sure that "channel" is not null (i.e. it exists)
    if (channel !== null)
        // Send our update message.
        channel.sendMessage(message);
});
```

Note that if your bot is public and is on other servers that you don't control, this is not advised as it is completely unprovoked and may anger some server owners.